# Regex to replace only certain commas

Tags: javascript

I need a regrex to replace commas are are between two characters that are no spaces.

Text: HOMER, Simpson,JACK, Daniels,NICK, Cage

Desired outcome: HOMER, Simpson - JACK, Daniels - NICK, Cage

This is what I could come up with but it replaces the letters as well as the comma

```
/[a-zA-z],[a-zA-z]/
```

Comment: Look into positive/negative look-aheads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"HOMER, Simpson,JACK, Daniels,NICK, Cage".replace(/(,(?!\s))/g, ' - ');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/sQKNN/

If you need to also check for leading space before a comma,

```
.replace(/((?!\s),(?!\s))/g, ' - '))
```

Comment: He wants to replace with ' - ', not ', '

Answer (score 3):

In regex, [`\S`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-white-space) represents all non-space characters.

```
var input  = "HOMER, Simpson,JACK, Daniels,NICK, Cage";

var output = input.replace(/(\S),(\S)/g, '$1 - $2');
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not too difficult to achieve.

- the `\S` character class represents all non-whitespace characters.
- You can use parentheses `()` to capture a *group*. In the replacement string, you can refer to each captured group with `$0` (which represents the entire match), `$1` (which represents the first group), `$2`, `$3` etc., which represent the subsequent groups.

The following code does what you want:

```
var input = "HOMER, Simpson,JACK, Daniels,NICK, Cage"
,   output = input.replace(/(\S),(\S)/g, '$1 - $2');
```

Do note that since `\s` is the equivalent of `[ \t\r\n]` (i.e. any of the following characters: space, tab, CR [carriage return], LF [line feed]), and `\S` is the inverse of `\s`, `\S` also will NOT match a tab or newline character.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
'HOMER, Simpson,JACK, Daniels,NICK, Cage'.replace(/([^\s]),([^\s])/gi, '$1 - $2');
```